# Can I use ng-model setter-getter option to transform the value of a variable in the model?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following situation in `angularjs`:

```
<select ng-model="value">
    <option ng-repeat="type in types">{{type.description}}</option>
<select>
```

The controller looks like:

```
$scope.value = null;
$scope.types=[{description: "asdf", id:"a"}, {description: "basdf", id:"b"}];
```

I want to set $scope.value, not with the value of `type.description`, but with the value of its corresponding id: `type.id`.  But I still want to show the description in the dropdown select.

Can I accomplish this using the getterSetter option of `ng-model`? I have looked the documentation and it does not clarify much.

Comment: You should use `ng-options` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need getterSetter to do that. All you need is [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions):

```
<select ng-model="value" ng-options="type.id as type.description for type in types">
</select>
```

Comment: This is better than what I was looking for. Thanks a lot. But for educational purposes, could what I wanted to achieve be done using getterSetter? If so, how?

Comment: Jadiel, any chance you figured this out? ngOptions/ngModel is acting inconsistantly for me when I use getterSetter values for the options and/or model. I can't figure out what I'm missing.